# CI pagination double query

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in CI Framework. For pagination i use two queries, one for required output using limit, and another to count total number of rows. Is there any other way like both can be done from single query?
My query is:

```
{
$searchtxt = $this->input->post('searchtxt');
        $datefrom = $this->input->post('fromdate');
        $todate = $this->input->post('todate');
        $status= $this->input->post('order_status');
        $sc_id = $this->input->post('sc_id');



    if($sc_id){
        $this->db->where('('.'o.requested_sc_id = '.$sc_id.' OR o.requesting_sc_id = '.$sc_id.')');


        //$this->db->where('o.requesting_sc_id =',$sc_id);
        }

    if ($status){
        $this->db->where('o.order_status =',$status);
        }
        if ($status != '' && $status == 0 ){
        $this->db->where('o.order_status = 0');
        }
    if($searchtxt){
        $this->db->like('o.order_number',$searchtxt);
    }
    if($datefrom)
    {           
        $this->db->where('o.order_dt >=', date("Y-m-d",date_to_timestamp($datefrom)));  
    }

    if($todate)
    {           
        $this->db->where('o.order_dt <=', date("Y-m-d",date_to_timestamp($todate)));    
    }
    if ($this->session->userdata('usergroup_id')!=1 && $this->session->userdata('usergroup_id')!= 2  && $this->session->userdata('usergroup_id')!=6 ){      

        $this->db->where('('.'o.requested_sc_id = '.$this->session->userdata('sc_id').' OR o.requesting_sc_id = '.$this->session->userdata('sc_id').')');
        //$this->db->where('o.requesting_sc_id = '.$this->session->userdata('sc_id'));
    }

    $this->db->select('o.order_id,o.order_number,o.order_dt,o.call_id,c.call_uid,o.order_status,o.order_dt,sc.sc_name,e.engineer_name');
    $this->db->from($this->table_name.' AS o');
    $this->db->join($this->mdl_callcenter->table_name.' AS c','c.call_id=o.call_id','left');
    $this->db->join($this->mdl_servicecenters->table_name.' AS sc' ,'sc.sc_id=o.requested_sc_id','left');
    $this->db->join($this->mdl_engineers->table_name.' AS e', 'e.engineer_id = o.engineer_id','left');
    $this->db->order_by('o.order_status ASC,o.order_dt DESC,o.order_created_ts DESC');
    if(isset($page['limit'])){
        $this->db->limit((int)$page['limit'],(int)$page['start']);
    }

    $result = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query(); 
    if ($status){
        $this->db->where('o.order_status =',$status);
        }
    if ($status != '' && $status == 0 ){
        $this->db->where('o.order_status = 0');
        }
    if($sc_id){
        $this->db->where('o.requesting_sc_id =',$sc_id);

        }
    if($searchtxt){
        $this->db->like('o.order_number',$searchtxt);
    }
    if($datefrom)
    {           
        $this->db->where('o.order_dt >=', date("Y-m-d",date_to_timestamp($datefrom)));  
    }

    if($todate)
    {           
        $this->db->where('o.order_dt <=', date("Y-m-d",date_to_timestamp($todate)));    
    }
    //if ($this->session->userdata('global_admin')!=1){     
    if ($this->session->userdata('usergroup_id')!=1 && $this->session->userdata('usergroup_id')!= 2  && $this->session->userdata('usergroup_id')!=6 ){  
        $this->db->where('o.requested_sc_id = '.$this->session->userdata('sc_id').' or o.requesting_sc_id = '.$this->session->userdata('sc_id'));
    }
    $this->db->select('o.order_id');
    $this->db->from($this->table_name.' AS o');
    $this->db->join($this->mdl_callcenter->table_name.' AS c','c.call_id=o.call_id','left');
    $this->db->join($this->mdl_servicecenters->table_name.' AS sc' ,'sc.sc_id=o.requested_sc_id','left');
    $this->db->join($this->mdl_engineers->table_name.' AS e', 'e.engineer_id = o.engineer_id','left');
    $result_total = $this->db->get();

    $orders['list'] = $result->result();
    $orders['total'] = $result_total->num_rows();
    return $orders;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the function as well

Comment: This is correct to get the total and result from two different queries. The totaling query will be without any limit range and the second query with a limit range to get the results.
@Nomi : I would definitely like to know how can you do both in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some explanation for this.

```
function($limit,$offset){

    $this->db
            ->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS emp", FALSE)
            ->select("*")
            ->from('tbl1')
            ->limit($limit, $offset);

    $data["query_result"] = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `Count`');
    $data["total_rows"] = $query->row()->Count;

    return $data;
}
```

Here you see you are forced to get total count using another query.
Of course this is not what you want but it is impossible with single query using mysql.
But here is a php way.

```
function($limit,$offset){

    $this->db
            ->select("*")
            ->from('tbl1');

    $data["query_result"] = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    $data["total_rows"] = array_slice($data["query_result"], $offset, $limit);

    return $data;
}
```

This can be achieved with single query but involves php to get the desired result.

Comment: What if the resultant data set is larger? Wouldn't it affect the execution time?

Comment: Well it will surely take much time. So there are three ways. Use with SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND. which is much slower. Use two queries which i think is fastest and use array_slice of php.

Comment: And IMHO, the second option, i.e two queries is the fastest.